# No HTTP2 traffic in gRPC call

Tags: tcp, grpc, http2

I am trying out a demo of gRPC protocol in python provided here. https://github.com/grpc/grpc/tree/master/examples/python/helloworld . There are 2 main scripts. One for a gRPC server and other for gRPC client. The server replies back with a "Hello, you" and then the client shuts down. I captured the network traffic during the while the client starts, contacts the server, gets replied with "Hello, you" and shuts down.

And there is no HTTP2 traffic in the network trace. (I have highlighted the particular TCP packet used for exchange of data.)

[image: Wireshark Network Capture]

What is the explanation here given that gRPC should use http2?

Comment: What makes you think this is not HTTP/2? In my opinion this looks like HTTP/2 although not HTTP/2 over TLS as typically use by the browsers but plain HTTP/2. Just because Wireshark does not mark it as HTTP/2 does not mean it is not - you might need to tell Wireshark that it should interpret this as HTTP/2 even though this is not the default port for it.

Comment: Ok. I digged through it's menu and asked it to interpret as http2. The way it is parsing it sensible enough. (Wireshark automatically detects http2, not sure what happened here)

Comment: Wireshark usually interprets protocols only for the typical ports of these protocols by default.